# Is there a third-party solution to sync google music with a desktop folder?

Tags: sync, google-music

Has anyone come up with a solution to sync the music files on Google Music with a desktop folder(s)? For example, after you uploaded a music file on Google Music, is erasing the file and uploading a new file the only way to edit the MP3 tags or change the album cover? For Picasa Web, Google's photo cloud, there is a clever solution by Gladinet (and maybe a few others) that creates copies of the files on Google Picasa Web and syncs any changes made to them.

What I'd like to have happen is keep a centralized music depository and make one change reflected in Google Music and all the other cloud storages (Dropbox, SkyDrive, etc.) that I may have. With other cloud storage, I can easily make this happen using Window's own symbolic link or a web-based service like IFTTT. The only bottleneck is the inability to sync Google Music with a desktop folder.

Any viable suggestion?

Comment: Which Windows version ?

Answer (score 1):

The following article explains about using Google Music, while also pointing out its shortcomings:
[How to Make Google Music Your Secondary Media Player](http://lifehacker.com/5882992/how-to-make-google-music-your-secondary-media-player-and-why-you-should).

These shortcomings are principally :

- Deleting files on your computer won't delete them in Google Music
- You can't re-upload files you've deleted from Google Music
- Sometimes it just gets wonky

A third-party solution in general involves abandoning Google Music as a storage media.

You can find heaps of alternative solutions in the article 
[Google Drive is not for everyone, so try these alternatives](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57419587-93/google-drive-is-not-for-everyone-so-try-these-alternatives/).

SugarSync sounds good, but the article also describes : Google Drive, Amazon Cloud Drive,
Dropbox, LogMeIn Cubby, CX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any third-party solutions. But what's wrong with the [first-party solution](https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1229970)?

> From the Google Play Music Manager, you can:
>
> - Upload music from your iTunes library, Windows Media Player
>     library, My Music folder, or folders of your choosing to Google Play
> - Choose to upload songs automatically or completely manually
> - Adjust the bandwidth available for uploading songs
> - View the progress of songs you’re uploading
> - Download any of the songs that you previously uploaded to your music 
>     library, as well as any song you purchased from the Google Play store

Whenever you change a tag, Music Manager should automatically [reupload](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809787) to Google Music.

Comment: Well. What you call "resync" is not really re-"sync". It's re-"uploading". If you re-read the article you hyperlinked, it will be clear.

By "sync", I mean automatic file update that doesn't involve the user's conscious or active uploading. To be exact, by "sync", it also has to be by-directional, like Dropbox or Google Drive. But here, I don't need bi-directional. A uni-directional automatic update from my local folder to Google Music would suffice.

Comment: @Anon "Choose to upload songs **automatically** or completely manually". "**Upload** music from... **folders of your choosing**". So it sounds like it will satisfy your need for uni-directional automatic updating. But no, it doesn't "sync" in the traditional sense of the word and I've changed my answer to reflect that. It doesn't work _exactly_ like Dropbox but it's the closest you're going to get right now. The Google Music API is still private and I don't know anyone making use of the [Unofficial Google Music API](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API) just yet.